# Open Browsers using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chromedriver, firefoxdriver, ie

I need to run my test case through chrome,Firefox and IE browsers in same time
so how can i open two or more browsers using one single instance of Webdiver?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually you can not open three browser with one webdriver instance hence we can create single object for browser with capabilities. You can use testNG to run multiple browser at a time

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of -
 https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/5431/how-to-open-multiple-browsers-using-webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TestNG using `@parameter` annotation you can run your test cases in different browsers.
In `testng.xml` File, you have to pass the browser value in the parameter tag which you have specified in the test case.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `Protractor`, which is almost a webdriver implementation for Angular based website automation, you can open multiple browsers at the same time , using `multicapabilities` in the `conf.js` file.

See [this](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#testing-against-multiple-browsers) for further reference